# Unable to understand the particular format of Cron?

Tags: cron

I have read the CronFormat to understand the Cron.But I am unable to understand this Cron Format:

According to my understand,the format is
    `<Minute> <Hour> <Day_of_the_Month> <Month_of_the_Year> <Day_of_the_Week>`

But I am unable to understand the below format.
    `07/10 * 1/1 *?*`

My Understanding:

My understanding of the above format is:
After Every 7 Minute,every hour and every month and every year.

Can anyone guide me what is it?
QuestionMark(?) and * I have not understood

Comment: the syntax `1/1` is quite useless, because it is the same as saying `*`. Regarding `*?*`, it is wrong. Check http://crontab.guru to understand such syntaxes.

Answer (score 0):

This is format of each cron job

```
# Example of job definition:
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7) OR sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  * user-name command to be executed
```

so 7/10 means 7th minute of every 10 minute,
next * means every hour,
1/1 also means every so every day.
Unfortunately I am also not aware of "?".

Comment: Okay.What is the difference between */1 and 1/1,*/7 and 7/10?

Comment: */1 and 1/1 does not make any difference.  where */7 means every 7th(minute/hour/day/month) while 7/10 means on every 7th(minute/hour/../) of every 10 (m/h/../)

Answer (score 0):

I like [this example](https://www.pantz.org/software/cron/croninfo.html) its easy for me to understand :-

```
# Minute |  Hour  | Day of Month |      Month |         Day of Week    |    Command    
# (0-59) | (0-23)  |   (1-31)  |  (1-12 or Jan-Dec) | (0-6 or Sun-Sat)                
    0    |    2      |    12    |         *     |           *      |      /usr/bin/find
```